# Propagate missing dates in teradata - select query

Tags: sql, date, teradata, missing-data

I have a table that looks like this:

| my_date | item_id. | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03-01 | GMZS72429 | 2 |
| 2020-03-07 | GMZS72429 | 2 |
| 2020-03-09 | GMZS72429 | 1 |
| 2020-03-04 | GMZS72425 | 1 |

And I want it to look like this

| my_date | item_id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03-01 | GMZS72429 | 2 |
| 2020-03-02 | GMZS72429 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2020-03-05 | GMZS72429 | 0 |
| 2020-03-06 | GMZS72429 | 0 |
| 2020-03-07 | GMZS72429 | 2 |
| 2020-03-08 | GMZS72429 | 0 |
| 2020-03-09 | GMZS72429 | 1 |
| 2020-03-01 | GMZS72425 | 0 |
| 2020-03-02 | GMZS72425 | 0 |
| 2020-03-03 | GMZS72425 | 0 |
| 2020-03-04 | GMZS72425 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2020-03-09 | GMZS72425 | 0 |

Since I was struggling with the documentation from Teradata, I have tried generating the pair `item_id - my_date` using another table, followed by a left join:

```
with a1 as(
select distinct my_date, item_id from some_table_with_the_item_ids_and_all_dates
) 
select a1.my_date, a1.item_id, coalesce(sales, 0) as sales
from a1 left join my_table on a1.item_id=my_table.item_id and a1.my_date=my_table.my_date;
```

This worked but it is terribly slow, and ugly. I was wondering if there is a better built-in (or alternative) method to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a use case for Teradata's EXPAND ON syntax:

```
select 
   new_date
  ,item_id 
  ,case when my_date = new_date then sales else 0 end
from
 (
   select dt.*, begin(p2) as new_date
   from
    (
      select t.*
         -- create a period for expansion in the next step
        ,period(my_date, lead(my_date, 1, my_date+1)
                         over (partition by item_id
                               order by my_date)) as pd
      from vt as t
    ) as dt
   -- now create the missing dates
   expand on pd as p2
 ) as dt
```

Comment: thanks, in case of different items, how can I adapt this? I edited the question to improve description

Comment: No need to adapt, this is ready for multiple items: `partition by item_id`

Answer (score 1):

One  simple option is to use Teradata's built in date view as your driver:

```
select
coalesce(v.my_date,c.calendar_date),
item_id,
coalesce(v.sales,0)
from
sys_calendar.calendar c
left join your_table v
    on v.my_date = c.calendar_date
where
    c.calendar_date between (select min(my_date) from your_table ) and (select max(my_date) from your_table)
order by 1
```

Comment: thanks, in case of different items, how can I adapt it? I edited the question to improve description

Comment: @Mstaino- Dnoeth's answer will already account for that (the partition by clause).